# TBB 4.5.1: Anonymity compromised if privacy settings are at default?

Tags: anonymity

I'm currently using Tor Browser Bundle version 4.5.1.

In order to pass the verifications set by Cloud Flare so as to gain access to certain websites, I've no choice but to choose the DEFAULT "Privacy Settings" in TBB 4.5.1.

Will the administrators of the websites that I visit know my real IP address through the use of cleverly crafted Javascripts embedded in certain web pages and/or the use of embedded web bugs or persistent cookies?

Answer (score 2):

Tor is able to ensure that your IP does not leak over the network. In the TBB there is currently no known way to accidentally disclose your IP via JavaScript. There are ways of doing this through DNS leakage, via HTML5 and Canvas, as well as WebRTC. But TBB is configured to disable those features/plugins by default.

Persistent cookies and browser fingerprint are always a concern but this risk is reduced a bit by TBB's configuration. These aren't examples of de-anonymization where the attacker finds the source IP, but rather cross-session attribution where the attacker can track your browsing habits across multiple sessions and IP's.